# Static constants set to default value in HLSL

Tags: directx, hlsl, directx11

I'm using dx11 and I'm working on SSAO. I am having wierd results, so I tried debugging it using RenderDoc and stepping through the pixel shader log, all the values of the static array seems to default to 0-vector. For example, look at r3-register in the following screenshot.

[image]

Here's the pixel shader I'm using. The global static variable that seems to be all null despite my initialization is the `gSSAOKernel`. Why is this? Isn't this correct?

```
#ifndef SSAO_PIXEL_HLSL
#define SSAO_PIXEL_HLSL

#include "Constants.h"
#include "Common.hlsl"

static const float gKernelSize = 16.0;
static const float gRadius = 1.5;
static const float gSSAOPower = 2.0;
static const float3 gSSAOKernel[gKernelSize] =
{
    float3(-0.0780436, 0.0558389, 0.0281286),
    float3(0.034318, -0.0635879, 0.0741237),
    float3(0.00230821, 0.0807279, 0.0805477),
    float3(0.0124638, 0.117585, 0.0578601),
    float3(0.093943, -0.0944602, 0.0816459),
    float3(0.139348, -0.109816, 0.0618508),
    float3(-0.181872, -0.129649, 0.0380075),
    float3(0.240066, -0.0494057, 0.118559),
    float3(0.115965, -0.0374714, 0.301286),
    float3(-0.294819, -0.100726, 0.225789),
    float3(-0.149652, 0.37459, 0.202967),
    float3(0.261695, -0.292813, 0.349015),
    float3(-0.37944, -0.425145, 0.206921),
    float3(0.628994, -0.189387, 0.224343),
    float3(-0.331257, -0.646864, 0.307335),
    float3(-0.467004, 0.439687, 0.618459),
};


cbuffer SSAOCBuffer : register(CBUFFER_REGISTER_PIXEL)
{
    float4x4 gViewProjMatrix;
    float4x4 gProjMatrix;
    float2 gScreenSize;
};

Texture2D gPositionTexture : register(TEXTURE_REGISTER_POSITION);
Texture2D gNormalTexture : register(TEXTURE_REGISTER_NORMAL);
Texture2D gNoiseTexture : register(TEXTURE_REGISTER_DIFFUSE);
Texture2D gDepthTexture : register(TEXTURE_REGISTER_DEPTH);
SamplerState gPointSampler : register(SAMPLER_REGISTER_POINT);

float linearizeDepth(in float depth, in float4x4 projMatrix) {
    return projMatrix[3][2] / (depth - projMatrix[2][2]);
}

float4 ssao(in float3x3 kernelBasis, in float3 originPos)
{
    float occlusion = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < gKernelSize; i++)
    {
        float3 samplePos = mul(kernelBasis, gSSAOKernel[i]);   <---------------------- this line
        samplePos *= gRadius * originPos;

        float4 offset = mul(gViewProjMatrix, float4(samplePos, 1.0));
        offset.xy /= offset.w;
        offset.xy = offset.xy * 0.5 + 0.5;

        float depth = gDepthTexture.Sample(gPointSampler, offset.xy).r;
        depth = linearizeDepth(depth, gProjMatrix);

        float rangeCheck = abs(originPos.z - depth) < gRadius ? 1.0 : 0.0;
        occlusion += (depth <= samplePos.z ? 1.0 : 0.0) * rangeCheck;

    }
    occlusion = 1.0 - (occlusion / float(gKernelSize));

    return pow(occlusion, gSSAOPower);
}

float4 ps_main(float4 position : SV_Position) : SV_Target0
{
    float2 coords = float2(1920.0, 1080.0) / float2(4.0, 4.0);
    coords *= float2(position.x / gScreenSize.x, position.y / gScreenSize.y);

    float3 originPos = gPositionTexture[uint2(position.xy)].xyz;
    float3 normal = gNormalTexture[uint2(position.xy)].xyz;

    float3 rvec = gNoiseTexture.Sample(gPointSampler, coords).xyz; //texture(uNoiseTex, noiseTexCoords).rgb * 2.0 - 1.0;
    float3 tangent = normalize(rvec - normal * dot(rvec, normal));
    float3 bitangent = cross(tangent, normal);
    float3x3 kernelBasis = CreateMatrixFromCols(tangent, bitangent, normal);

    return ssao(kernelBasis, originPos);// gFinalTexture.Sample(gPointSampler, coords);//float4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}

#endif
```

Also - offtopic, but this pixelshader murders my framerate, all the way from solid 450+ to 80-90. I guess with all the texture lookups the technique is simply expensive, but still, I must be doing something wrong in regard to performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my fault - the 0 values are caused by a bug in RenderDoc v0.20 - the x0[] indexable temp register being used there which contains your kernel data wasn't implemented in the shader debugging at the time of that release - [I implemented it a few months ago](https://github.com/baldurk/renderdoc/commit/c274169de38b84258889c88d76d73659e4547a96). I'm hoping to get v0.21 with all the latest fixes out this week-ish.

Comment: Oh ok, that was unexpected. Thanks and btw awesome debugging software.